# Bilinear resampling yields inaccurate/small values (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, interpolation, resampling, precipitation

I am trying to upscale / resample some GSMaP observations from 0.1 x 0.1 degrees to 30m. I want the resolution to match Landsat 8 so that I can perform some modeling.

But in Google Earth Engine when I resample using bilinear interpolation, the GSMaP values don't geographically overlap the original values well, and they are also significantly smaller. Because the original cells are so large, I thought at least some of the new resampled cells would have the same values as the original image, given that values are based on the 4 nearest neighbors. Instead, the values are significantly smaller. E.g. the red GSMap cells have a precip rate of 42 mm/hr, the resampled cells have a rate of 4 mm/hr.

Any ideas? I'm not sure if I am resampling incorrectly in Earth Engine, or misunderstanding the technique.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/73e2becea4a5ff86594f8bb40a46183a

PS. The resampled layer is transparent in Earth Engine but changing the opacity does not make it opaque. Would like to know if there is a way to fix that as well.

Answer (score 3):

This question is over 2 years old, but I was having the same issue and worked out what was going wrong, so here is my answer.

The problem is in how Google Earth Engine handles projections. The help documentation for the `ee.Image.resample()` method includes the warning: "This relies on the input image's default projection being meaningful, and so cannot be used on composites, for example. (Instead, you should resample the images that are used to create the composite.)". What happens in practice is that when you create a composite image using `mosaic()` or `mean()` or similar, its projection information is lost and it is assigned a default CRS of EPSG:4326 (longitude-latitude) with a 1-degree resolution. Then when you try to resample to a finer resolution, it smears out the values because it thinks the resolution is much coarser than it is.

For your example, you can fix it by re-assigning the original projection and scale to the composite layer using the `ee.Image.setDefaultProjection()` before resampling. In the sample code, you also need to specify the Landsat 8 projection and scale that you are resampling to, since Landsat 8 is in a different projection to the precipitation data:

```
// Dataset to be resampled
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/operational')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-08-06', '2018-08-07'))
                  .filterBounds(geometry);
var precipitation = dataset.select('hourlyPrecipRate');

// Also import Landsat 8 images for the region for reprojection
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-08-01', '2018-08-31'))
  .filterBounds(geometry);

// Create a separate variable for the composite image
var precipitation_mosaic = precipitation
  .mosaic()
  .clip(geometry);

// Note projection and scale of mosaic have reverted to EPSG:4326 and 1-degree resolution
print("default projection of composite", precipitation_mosaic.projection(),
  "scale", precipitation_mosaic.projection().nominalScale());

// Extract projection information for original dataset (precipitation) and target (Landsat 8)
var dataset_proj = precipitation.first().projection();
var target_proj = landsat.first().projection();

// Re-assign original projection to precipitation mosaic
precipitation_mosaic = precipitation_mosaic.setDefaultProjection(dataset_proj);

var precipitation_30m = precipitation_mosaic.resample('bilinear').reproject(target_proj).clip(geometry);

// Add to map
Map.centerObject(precipitation_mosaic, 8);

var precipitationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 30.0,
  palette:
      ['1621a2', 'ffffff', '03ffff', '13ff03', 'efff00', 'ffb103', 'ff2300'],
};
Map.addLayer(precipitation_mosaic, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
Map.addLayer(precipitation_30m, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation30');
```